# setOnItemSelectedListener : application stops working

Tags: android, listener

I'm new to android , and I'm trying to make editText to get visible while selecting an Item ,the code seems to be fine , but the emulator stops working anytime I run the application and click on the button that accesses that activity .Here is my code :

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ManageActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {



    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.manage, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a NewCaseFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

            if(position == 0){
            Fragment fragment = new NewCaseFragment();
            //Bundle args = new Bundle();
            //args.putInt(NewCaseFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            //fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;

            }
            else{
                Fragment fragment = new UpdateFragment();
                return fragment;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A  fragment representing a section of the app
     */
    public static class NewCaseFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener{


        public NewCaseFragment() {
        }

        Button members ;
        EditText orgname ,  orgaddress;
        //Spinner spinner1;




       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newcase,
                    container, false);

            Button members = (Button)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.members);
            EditText orgname = (EditText)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.orgname);
            EditText orgaddress = (EditText)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.orgaddress);

            Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);           
            //members.setOnClickListener(membersListener);

            return rootView;
        }

       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner1, View view,int pos, long id)
       {
        orgname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        orgaddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

       }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    }


    /*******
     * 
     */

public static class UpdateFragment extends Fragment {


        public UpdateFragment() {
        }

       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.updatecase,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


}
```

the layout :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/casename"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/casename"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/organisation"
        android:prompt="@string/infoorg" />




        <!-- layout for organisation information -->



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/orgname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/orgname"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:visibility="gone"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/orgaddress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/orgaddress"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/staff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hint="@string/staff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/members"
                style="@style/btnStyleGrey"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/users2"
                android:text="@string/plus" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/staff"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            style="@style/btnStyleBlue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/submit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the log :

```
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at com.pfe.risu.ManageActivity$NewCaseFragment.onCreateView(ManageActivity.java:195)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1011)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:880)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1374)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-09 18:01:44.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

To solve the second problem :

now I get the null pointer exception on these lines :

```
orgname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
orgaddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I I initialised the variable inside the onItemSelected method :

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner1, View view,int pos, long id)
       {


           EditText orgname = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.orgname);
            EditText orgaddress = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.orgaddress);

        orgname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        orgaddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

       }
```

I'm getting no exceptions but the on ItemSelectedListner doesn't seem to be working , and the EditTexts are visible :(

After replacing

EditText orgname = (EditText)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.orgname);
       EditText orgaddress = (EditText)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.orgaddress);

with

```
EditText orgname = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.orgname);
 EditText orgaddress = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.orgaddress);
```

ManageActivity shows that the EditTexts are invisible , but then the application stops again . Here is the log :

```
    05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at com.pfe.risu.ManageActivity$NewCaseFragment.onItemSelected(ManageActivity.java:208)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:882)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:848)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-09 20:58:24.401: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is line 208 :

```
orgname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Have you checked the LogCat output? Probably some Exception is thrown that stops the Emulator (or your app at least). Check the LogCat and if you don't find the answer there, add the relevant part to your question here, so others may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your variables

```
EditText orgname;        
EditText orgaddress;
Button members;
```

So when you're doing

```
members.setOnClickListener(membersListener);
orgname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
orgaddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

A `NullPointerException` is thrown and your app stops

**EDIT :**

You have to get your variable with the `view` that you inflated :

Replace :

```
Button members = (Button)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.members);
EditText orgname = (EditText)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.orgname);
EditText orgaddress = (EditText)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.orgaddress);
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

By :

```
Button members = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.members);
EditText orgname = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.orgname);
EditText orgaddress = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.orgaddress);
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

**EDIT :**

Replace:

```
EditText orgname = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.orgname);
 EditText orgaddress = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.orgaddress);
```

By :

```
EditText orgname = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.orgname);
EditText orgaddress = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.orgaddress);
```

Comment: I think you're right , the logcat shows a nullpointerException ,but I've inirialised the variables , the application still stops and the exception is thrown .

Comment: Could you post the logcat pls ? On which line do you get the NPE ?

Comment: I don't know on which line I get it , I added the logcat on my question

Comment: What's wrote on line 195 of Manage Activity ?

Comment: spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: I edited my code , but when I ran it for the first time it did show the first screen of the manageActivity but it stopped about 1 sec after that , then I tryed running it for a seconf time and I get this error : 
[2013-05-09 19:18:28 - Risu] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: It is not an error message, it is a warning. What the system is trying to tell you: The application on the device is the same as your application in Eclipse. And because the application is already running on the device, the system tells you that it is not going to kill and restart it, but bring the activity of your already running app into the foreground. Accept this answer if it has resolve your problem and re-ask a new question

Comment: now I get the null pointer exception on these lines :
orgname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     orgaddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: I did but I still get the null pointer exception on these lines : orgname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); orgaddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);